# dataset from tf.data.Dataset.save(load) for GCS + TPU got NotFoundError Could not find metadata file. [Op:MakeIterator]

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, tpu

I tried this both on `TF 2.8` and `Nightly (2.10.0-dev20220616)` on Colab. In 2.8, i used the experimental version of this API. I am trying this in the context of trying to train a huggingface bert model. The dataset has gone through several transformations to arrive at a tf dataset proper.

To repro:

1. In a session without TPU, source/construct the `dataset`
2. use `tf.data.Dataset.save(train_set, 'gs://ai-tests/data/train_set')`. I tried to read it back with load and able to iterate through it (it seems to work here).
3. In a separate TPU session, i tried to get `train_set = tf.data.Dataset.load('gs://ai-tests/data/train_set')`
4. Iterating get error

   for x in train_set:
   break

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> ```
>
> in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
> 7207 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
> 7208   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
> -> 7209   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> 7210
> 7211
>
> ```
> NotFoundError: Could not find metadata file. [Op:MakeIterator]
> ```

Comment: I have read suggestion somewhere that reconstructing the tf dataset as a tfrecord and then save it on GCS should make it work. I tend to think so since i have trained with TPU using tfrecord based tf.dataset successfully. But would really love this new API’s convenience, and hope it may be a bug that could be fixed.

Comment: Have you tried `get train_set = tf.data.Dataset.load(“gs://ai-tests/data/train_set”)` **with double quotation marks** instead of single quotation marks as you post it, as suggested [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/gcs#how)?

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez Highly doubt if the quote marks matter, never seen it matter 99.9% of the time with python. Also, this works in a non TPU session.